# Micro-USB headphone support in Android

Tags: headphones, headphone-jack

I have a micro-usb headphone (from my LG GS155 phone that is a feature phone).

I plugged it to my Xperia Mini Pro (Android 4.0) but it did not work.

Is Micro-USB headphone supported by Android? How does it should be configured to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The “Micro-USB” headphone used by LG GS155 is not really an USB device — it just uses the USB connector for the same analog audio signals as in usual 3.5 or 2.5 mm round connectors. Look at the [MicroUSB to 3.5 or 2.5 jack headset pinout](http://pinoutsguide.com/HeadsetsHeadphones/microusb_headset_pinout.shtml).

In order to work with such headsets, the phone needs to have the appropriate hardware to detect the type of connected device and switch functions of USB port pins from USB to analog audio. It is highly unlikely that the phone will have such hardware if it also has a standard 3.5 or 2.5 mm audio connector. Even older HTC phones using the proprietary “ExtUSB” connector compatible with Mini-USB did not switch pin functions when a headset is connected — [they used separate pins for audio](http://pinouts.ru/HeadsetsHeadphones/htc_extusb_headset_pinout.shtml).

The only way to connect this headphone to your new phone is to build an adapter with a 3.5 mm plug and a Micro-USB Type B receptacle connector, so that the headphone will be connected to the audio circuit through the 3.5 mm audio connector on the phone.

Comment: Some Motorola phones have both a 3.5mm connector and support audio via the USB connector; they apparently use a specific resistance across two of the USB pins to indicate that it's an audio device rather than USB.   This functionality is used by their car and desk docks to provide a 3.5mm audio out connection in the dock or via a special adaptor cable... which doesn't help with your Experia, buy may be of interest to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a driver is definitely needed at least.

Take a look at this [XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1145394) and this [Acer Tablet Forum post](http://www.acertabletforum.com/forum/acer-iconia-tab-accessories/693-usb-headset-compatibility.html).

Comment: These posts are about real USB devices, which could be connected to Android devices with USB host (OTG) support. But the headphone in question is not really an USB device — it is just a simple analog headphone using the standard-looking Micro-USB connector for nonstandard functions.